# How to parse this JSON Array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending and Parsing JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-in-android)

**EDIT**: Finally I found an answer to get array value without key value by using `Iterator`. I just got an idea from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515018/getting-the-string-value-from-a-json-arrays-object-in-java)

I am just newbie to JSON Parsing, and I have no idea how to parse this kinda `JSONArray`. Can anyone give me a hint ?

```
{

 "pages": [
      "image1.jpg",
      "image2.jpg"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't JSON.parse work in android? that's an array **inside** an object by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand the basic concepts of JSON .

`{}` talks about an instance (called JSONObject)
`[]` talks about an array of somethings (called JSONArray in Android)
`"xxx":"yyy"` talks about key & value

First, you may let the reply json string become an JSONObject, `JSONObject replyJSON = new JSONObject(reply)`

Then, get the JSONArray named 'pages' inside the replied JSONObject,  `JSONArray pagesArray = replyJSON.getJSONArray("pages")`

Finally, get the value inside the JSONArray by the method `getString`, in your example, you may use pagesArray.getString(0) and pagesArray.getString(1)

Check out the documentation for more details:
[JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject%28int%29)

Comment: thanks for your info. is it possible to get all the datas from pages array without using `pagesArray.getString(0)`nor (1) ?

Comment: you may get the length of the JSONArray by using `.length()` and iterate though the JSONArray :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `new JSONObject(json)`; where json is the variable that stores your json string.

Comment: then read [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) article which is the first google result for "android json parser"

Comment: Rather than comment on your own answer, you can add this new information by clicking "edit".

Comment: this isn't part of my answer, it is more of a remark on the quality of the question.

Comment: my problem is that i don't have Key Value in `pages` Array. is there any way to get the whole data from `pages` Array with single line of code ?

Answer (score -2):

Use the JQuery function `parseJSON`:

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(string);
```

Comment: The asker asked how to do it in android

Comment: I believe, the OP is requesting how to parse JSON in Java on Android.  Not in a browser and not using jQuery.