# How to parse this Json Array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I have a jsonArray which I want to parse in my android app.

The array:-

```
[
   {
      "id": 96905,
      "category": "topup",
      "detail": "Full talktime of Rs.55 + 1 local airtel SMS free for 1 day",
      "price": 55,
      "keywords": "topup",
      "updated": "2016-01-07 00:16:23.0",
      "validity": "7 days",
      "service": "Airtel",
      "sourceUri": "https://pay.airtel.com/online-payments/recharge.jsp",
      "circle": "Assam",
      "talktime": 55
   },

   {
      "id": 90397,
      "category": "topup",
      "price": 510,
      "keywords": "topup",
      "updated": "2016-01-07 00:16:23.0",
      "service": "Airtel",
      "sourceUri": "https://pay.airtel.com/online-payments/recharge.jsp",
      "circle": "Assam",
      "talktime": 520
   },
   {
      "id": 90399,
      "category": "topup",
      "price": 1000,
      "keywords": "topup",
      "updated": "2016-01-07 00:16:23.0",
      "service": "Airtel",
      "sourceUri": "https://pay.airtel.com/online-payments/recharge.jsp",
      "circle": "Assam",
      "talktime": 1020
   }]
```

My android Code:-

Asynctask:-

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            try {
                JSONObject jo;
               JSONArray ja2 = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://app.ireff.in:9090/IreffWeb/android?service=airtel&circle=assam");

                for (int i = 0; i < ja2.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jo = ja2.getJSONObject(i);   
                    map.put("rank", jo.getString("price"));
                    map.put("country", jo.getString("validity"));
                    map.put("population", jo.getString("talktime"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

JsonFunctions.java

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONArray jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

The error I get:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The json is hosted [here](http://app.ireff.in:9090/IreffWeb/android?service=airtel&circle=assam)

I was following [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/) tutorial for learning json parsing, but this tutorial uses jsonObject and I am not able to parse the json array.

Not a duplicate to this :-[Sending and Parsing JSON Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818697/sending-and-parsing-json-objects) or this [How to parse this JSON Array in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876091/how-to-parse-this-json-array-in-android)

Comment: You can learn about NullPointerException => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: validity is not in second object

Comment: Also httpclient is deprecated. Use httpurlconnection instead

Comment: I am able to parse the json sucessfully if i supply it as a local string, but i am facing the issue when trying to download it from the internet, so validity works

Comment: @Raghunandan sure, I will do that, but can you please say at present what is wrong

Comment: @Sleez Your json array is null. Log what you get from server

Comment: Are you check this value ``result = sb.toString();`` , it not null ???

Comment: @DanhDC yes it is null wierdly, I do not know why, The original link given by the tutorial does not give null

Comment: Please change ``HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);`` to ``HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);``

Comment: This tutorial really helps you and most advanced tutorial for future development.
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: Here JSONArray ja2 = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://app.ireff.in:9090/IreffWeb/android?service=airtel&circle=assam");
whats the value for ja2 you are getting?it could be null.

Comment: @DanhDC I am getting different json, But tell me, why does the original link given in the tutorial work but not this link, i mean i am getting different json values compared on PC and mobile.

Comment: @Sleez the result of tutorial have format ``worldpopulation: [-json array]`` , it have **JsonArray Name** is **worldpopulation**. And look again tutorial code, it use ``jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
``

Comment: I am getting Unauthorized server access when I am trying to use HttpGet

Comment: If use **POST** method, you can add new string to result like : ``{
- jsonArrayName: put your arr result here
}`` , then use same tutorial  ``JSONObject ob= new  JSONObject(result);
        jArray = ob.getJSONArray("jsonArrayName");``

Comment: but the original tutorial is using post method itself and it is able to retrive the json, why is the same not possibe with the new link ?

Comment: About **Unauthorized** exception, you can look around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283996/android-httpclient-authentication-always-returns-401-code

Comment: i agree to Danh..comment above,still hv described in detail again -    wrap the overall jsonarray into jsonobject at server end then from jsonobject fetch the jsonarray.ex: {"jsonListName":["id":"value1","category":"value2"]}

JSONObject jo = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://app.ireff.in:9090/IreffWeb/android?service=airtel&circle=assam");
if(jo !=null){
JSONArray ja2=jo.getJSONArray("jsonListName");
if(ja2!=null){
// iterate parse json and fetch value for id and category here
}
}

Comment: @DanhDC The unauthorized exception is comming only if i used HttpGet not for HttpPost

Comment: @Sleez check your host **http://app.ireff.in:9090** , maybe it need some permission, so you can add some scope ``AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT``

Comment: Sure, But is the permission to view from PC(which i am able to do without having any permission) vs parsing json from android is different ?

Comment: @Sleez look around stackoverflow with key **android httpclient unauthorized** , i think have many solution can help you

Comment: whats the service used at back end? if using wcf then this could help
//server configuration
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/android?service={strser}&circle={strc}")]
        string android(string USRID, string PWD);

//method declaration
 public string android(string service,string circle){
          string strser = service.Trim();
          string User_IMEINo = strIMEI.Trim();
          return "";}

Comment: Please clarify on point the null pointer is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `BufferReader` is not working as expected in your class **JSONfunctions** , do some changes in your class and it should looks like

**JSONfunctions.java**

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }


       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        URL urls = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection;
        urlConnection = urls.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
         String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
            result=sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
      catch (Exception e) {}
    try {

        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
   }
  }
```

and to avoid Exception check if `JSONArray` is not null then only it goes to run `for` loop like this :

```
 JSONArray ja2 =   JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://app.ireff.in:9090/IreffWeb/android?  service=airtel&circle=assam");
 if(ja2!=null)
            for (int i = 0; i < ja2.length(); i++) {}
```

Comment: what is the difference between my JsonFunctions class and your class ? It worked...I am checking everything now

Comment: @Sleez i think your `is = entity.getContent();` returning blank or null that's why your BufferedReader cant read blank inputStream

Comment: It is showing only 4 json values, not all json values

Comment: Ok, i got it, there is a field not available in All places, Thanks, it fixed my code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer an *alternate* solution (of sorts). A much simpler version of your existing code would be:

Updated code:

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestListActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String url = "http://app.ireff.in:9090/IreffWeb/android?service=airtel&circle=assam";

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true);

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);

        try {
            Response response = call.execute();
            String strResult = response.body().string();
            JSONArray JARoot = new JSONArray(strResult);

            for (int i = 0; i < JARoot.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JORoot = JARoot.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                if (JORoot.has("category") && JORoot.getString("category").equals("topup"))   {

                    if (JORoot.has("id")) {
                        map.put("id", JORoot.getString("id"));
                    }

                    if (JORoot.has("category")) {
                        map.put("category", JORoot.getString("category"));
                    }

                    if (JORoot.has("detail")) {
                        map.put("detail", JORoot.getString("detail"));
                    } else {
                        map.put("detail", null);
                    }

                    if (JORoot.has("price")) {
                        map.put("price", JORoot.getString("price"));
                    }

                    /** ADD THE COLLECTED DATA TO THE ARRAY LIST **/
                    arraylist.add(map); /* THE DATA WILL ONLY BE ADDED IF THE CATEGORY = "topup" */
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        ListView testList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testList);
        TestListAdapter adapter = new TestListAdapter(TestListActivity.this, arraylist);
        testList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class TestListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;

    // LAYOUTINFLATER TO USE A CUSTOM LAYOUT
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    // ARRAYLIST TO GET DATA FROM THE ACTIVITY
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrItem;

    public TestListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrItem) {

        this.activity = activity;

        // CAST THE CONTENTS OF THE ARRAYLIST IN THE METHOD TO THE LOCAL INSTANCE
        this.arrItem = arrItem;

        // INSTANTIATE THE LAYOUTINFLATER
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // A VIEWHOLDER INSTANCE
        ViewHolder holder;

        // CAST THE CONVERTVIEW IN A VIEW INSTANCE
        View vi = convertView;

        // CHECK CONVERTVIEW STATUS
        if (convertView == null)    {
            // CAST THE CONVERTVIEW INTO THE VIEW INSTANCE vi
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_item, null);

            // INSTANTIATE THE VIEWHOLDER INSTANCE
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            /*****  CAST THE LAYOUT ELEMENTS    *****/

            /* TOP (PRIMARY) ELEMENTS */
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            holder.txtDetail = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);

            // SET THE TAG TO "vi"
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // CAST THE VIEWHOLDER INSTANCE
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        if (arrItem.get(position).get("price") != null)    {
            String strPrice = arrItem.get(position).get("price");
            holder.txtPrice.setText("PRICE:  " + strPrice);
        }

        if (arrItem.get(position).get("detail") != null)   {
            String strDetail = arrItem.get(position).get("detail");
            holder.txtDetail.setText("DETAIL: " + strDetail);
        } else {
            holder.txtDetail.setText("DETAIL: NA");
        }

        return vi;
    }

    private class ViewHolder    {

        /* TOP (PRIMARY) ELEMENTS */
        TextView txtPrice;
        TextView txtDetail;
    }
}
```

*For the sake of completeness, I am also including the code for the `adapter`. It is a simple implementation. Do clean it up / optimize it / customize as per your requirement.*

1. This piece of code has been tested prior to being posted (see screenshot of Logs at the bottom)
2. This uses the [OkHttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Add this `compile` statement to the *dependencies* section of the module's gradle file: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'`. Check the link for an updated version.
3. The example code uses `if` statements considering that not every record has the same set of nodes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is okhttp ? a dependency ?

Comment: @Sleez: Correct. It's a library by [Square](http://square.github.io/). Just add `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'` to your Gradle file, sync it and you'll be all set.

Comment: Cannot resolve methods okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            okHttpClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true);

Comment: @Sleez you will need to add the `compile...` to your gradle mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: yes yes, i have added the file, only those 3 methods have problem

Comment: @Sleez: Use the version in the updated and post. The 3.0.0 might have changed something. Change that bit to `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'`

Comment: thanks for ur help, I feel this solution works as i can see my logs giving output, but it is crashing as i am trying to populate my list, so can you please tell me a solution accordingly ? More specifically this error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ListViewAdapter.getCount(ListViewAdapter.java:34)

Comment: @Sleez: Give me a couple of minutes while I cook up a full working solution.

Comment: Super thanks, much thanks, billion thanks. 2 questions which rom is that and what are the advantages of okhttp over normal http method

Comment: @Sleez: You are welcome. For your first question, that's actually a Xiaomi Redmi 2 Prime with the MIUI ROM on it. And second, OkHttp is faster as against the standard HTTP. It has compression, low latency and several of the good things. I have always preferred it over stock HTTP for a couple of years now.

Comment: Dhanyavaad IceMAN :-)

Comment: @Sleez Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: One last question, as you can see the json has many objects, i want to display/parse only those objects which has "category" as "topup", how to do that?

Comment: @Sleez: That simple enough. Check the update in the post. Specifically, the first `if` statement at the start of the `for` loop. ;-)

Comment: Dude, this question should be given oscar, i was using if(JORoot.getString("category")=="topup"), nvm, we all learn, dhanyavaad so much

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonResponse="";
for(int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

    String id = person.getString("id");
    String category = person.getString("category");
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful

Comment: http is deprecated so use volley library and in volley u can get the response and from reponse u can use JsonArray and JsonObject to extract it from response